# TCP connection does not work on remote host

Tags: java, android, tcp

I would like to connect with remote server using TCP socket.

When the client and server are connected to the same network everything works fine. There is a request sent from the Android client and a response from server received, After connecting to different networks, the server gets my message from Android host but did not respond.

I am testing this connection with the free Google Play Telnet and TCP application and it works fine, so I think that the problem is in my code.

```
 public static void onsocket() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Socket socket = null;


    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF();
        Log.w(TAG, "Response from server: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if (socket != null){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataOutputStream != null){
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dataInputStream != null){
            try {
                dataInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use methods other than writeUTF/readUTF (write&flush/read), but I get the same result.

Comment: Can your server ping your Android host? If not, you have an (off-topic) routing problem.

Comment: As I wrote other application could send response to my device and ping  works correctly.

Comment: You can't use `readUTF()` unless the other end is using `writeUTF(),` and *vice versa.*